# Android: Include layout file from another module's resources

Tags: android, android-layout

I working on project PROJ which consist of 2 modules com.example.MOD1 and com.example.MOD2,
in MOD2's resource man_layout.xml i want to include sub_layout.xml from MOD1. I do:

MOD2/res/layout/man_layout.xml:

```
<include
    layout="@com.example.MOD1:layout/sub_layout"/>
```

But I got error:

```
No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout' with value '@com.example.MOD1:layout/sub_layout').
```

How to include resources from another module within same project? I use android studio and need to reuse same resources in group of projects. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use resources from com.example.MOD1 in com.example.MOD2 com.example.MOD1 must be a library project.

Answer (score 0):

Also, when you link the module com.example.MOD1 in com.example.MOD2's build.gradle, you MUST also specify it's a 'compile'-level dependency (if you mark it as 'provided', resource id's won't be resolved).